# @JoinColumn difference between name and ForeignKey

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@JoinColumn(name="user_id", foreignKey=@ForeignKey(name= "FK_VERIFY_USER"))
private User user;
```

Where is the difference between "name='user_id'" and "foreignKey=.."?

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Answer (score 0):

From the API Doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html

**name**

(Optional) The name of the foreign key column.

**foreignKey**

(Optional) Used to specify or control the generation of a foreign key constraint when table generation is in effect.